# writing and reading a txt content using java

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I want to read data from a text file and columns are seperated by a space like this

```
1 BNA 5000 10.81
1 CER 1000 20.33
1 ADV 500 1.91
1 MNT 20000 5.53
```

and I want to write data----------------- to a text file in the same format,, 
and it'd be grateful  if you could tell me how to write data----------------- continuosly

ex : I write some information today in a txt file and whenever i decide to write some informations again i want to use same txt file and the earlier data should also be there..

Comment: What did you learn from the multiple tutorials you've read?

Comment: i wanted to try something differrent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append to existing file use `FileWriter` with append = true argument in constructor:

```
FileWriter fileWriter= new FileWriter(fileName,true);
BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
bufferWriter.write(inputString);
bufferWriter.close();
```

Read more about `FileWriter` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

Answer (score 0):

For appending text content to a file you can use a FileWriter. Use the constructor with 2 args (2nd has to be "true") to append (further info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean) )

See http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-append-content-to-file-in-java/ for a quick example.

Comment: Welcome To Stack Overflow! Instead of pasting a link to a solution, you should also add the relevant code from the link in your answer.  That way if the link ever goes down the answer is still available.